# When are JS object variables assigned a value?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm just a little confused as to when Object variables are assigned a value.

As far as I remember (and this is from long-lost and hazy Java knowledge so may not be relevant), object variables are initialised prior to constructor calls. I had thought that explicitly declared values would be too, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

For example:

I've a parent class, `Shape`:

```
class Shape {
  constructor(data) {
    this._data = data;
    this._data.markup = this._generateMarkup();
  }
}
```

and a child, `Circle`:

```
class Circle extends Shape {
  _elementName = 'test';
  
  constructor(data) {
    super(data);
    console.log({data});
  }
  
  _generateMarkup() {
     console.log(this._elementName);
    return `<div class="${this._elementName}">Test</div>`
  }
}
```

`this._elementName` is returning `undefined`.

This could well be a mistake on my part, but why is `_generateMarkup()` - essentially a property of the child - accessible in the parent constructor, but `_elementName` is not?

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/rNrNdYQ?editors=0011)

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(data) {
    this._data = data;
    this._data.markup = this._generateMarkup();
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  _elementName = 'test';
  
  constructor(data) {
    super(data);
    console.log({data});
  }
  
  _generateMarkup() {
     console.log(this._elementName);
    return `<div class="${this._elementName}">Test</div>`
  }
}

new Circle({});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the *properties* of a class are added and initialized in the constructor.
The `_generateMarkup` is not a property per se, it's a method on the class; it's defined before the constructor is called.

In this case if you want the `_elementName` to be defined and have a value, you need to add it to the constructor code:

```
constructor() {
  ...
  this._elementName = 'test';
  ...
}
```

On a sidenote, it's generally a bad practice to call methods which aren't inherited or defined on the class.

Comment: this also cant be done in the Circle class as super must run first? so `generateMarkup` will never have access to `_elementName` post-assignment?

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I think that is where java differs. So really I should probably either just call the `_generateMarkup` function in each child, or define the `_elementName` in the parent and pass the value up in the call to `super`?

Comment: Yeah, this: https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/ExpapqJ?editors=0011 seems like the easiest fix to me? Not sure why I wasn't doing this tbh

Comment: You could try this:
`
class Shape {
  constructor(data, elementName = 'shape') {
    this._data = data;
 this._elementName = elementName;
 this._data.markup = this._generateMarkup();
  }
  
  _generateMarkup() {
    console.log(this._elementName);
    return `<div class="${this._elementName}">Test</div>`
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data, 'test');
    console.log({data});
  }
  
}

new Circle({});
`

Comment: when it comes to JavaScript OOP, i'd just take working and run with it. This area of the language makes my head spin. Will jump on MDN some point to understand this better. [this seems to be a good place to start on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_programming)

Comment: @IgorK. Yeah that also works well. Guess it's just a choice of the bad practice but convenient option or the more repetitive calls in each child. Thanks for the help

Comment: @damonholden yeah, you aren't wrong. Luckily I quite like OOP, but JS' implementation appears to be a bit of a mirage. Big fan of Will Sentence's courses on JS OOP. Can't rememeber what his site is called, but it's also on Frontend Masters